# What observer need to use for NO-COUPON code apply option in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

In magento Shopping cart price rules, I need to customize NO-COUPON code option in store basis.I have completed the coupon code option(Store basis) when we enter the coupon code and submit. Magento have no-coupon code option in which discount amount automatically has been applied. But I don't know how to customize NO-COUPON code option.Where can I add a condition to apply coupon code automatically only for selected stores.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event Name : `salesrule_validator_process`

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
                        'rule'    => $rule,
                        'item'    => $item,
                        'address' => $address,
                        'quote'   => $quote,
                        'qty'     => $qty,
                        'result'  => $result,
                    ));
```

And follow steps  [link here](http://www.webguys.de/magento/turchen-21-kostenlose-produkte-uber-warenkorb-preisregeln/)