# Attribute inventory qty for cart rules

Tags: attributes, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to create a shopping cart rule where free shipping will be given to certain products provided they have an inventory `qty` greater than 1.

Quantity (`qty`) is not a visible attribute in the attributes manager so I cant set it to use for promotion rules.

How do you enable the attribute inventory `qty` to be available for shopping cart rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if it's not too necessary for you to have a custom attribute for checking `inventory` of product(in catalog not cart) in Magento then, you can also achieve this using an event-observer.

You just have to observe event `salesrule_validator_process` this will fire just before the rule is applied, and with this you can check if the product's inventory meets your criteria(greater than 1) than only the rule will be validated to `true`.

Just create an observer like below:
app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
        <events>
            <salesrule_validator_process>
                <observers>
                    <company_module_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkInventory</method>
                    </company_module_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </salesrule_validator_process>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Observer.php like below:

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Model_Observer extends Varien_Event_Observer {
    public function checkInventory($observer) {
        $quoteItems = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        foreach($quoteItems as $item):
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);
            if(//Your product id or category condition) {
                if($stock->getQty() > 1.0000) {
                    //Do you stuff here
                }
            }
        endforeach;
    }
}
```

Refer below links for more info.

[What observer need to use for NO-COUPON code apply option in magento?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94571/what-observer-need-to-use-for-no-coupon-code-apply-option-in-magento)

http://www.webguys.de/magento/turchen-21-kostenlose-produkte-uber-warenkorb-preisregeln/

**Hope this helps you out.**

Comment: If you still didn't got a way to do this, I have updated my answer with code example, check it.

Comment: The module is a nice touch but ultimately your comment about custom attribute is what gave me the idea to do just that and have the stock replicated there, Thank you!